# What is the difference between "[ -h" and "[ -L" in bash?

Tags: bash

```bash
if [ -h "demo" ]; then
    echo "-h: true"
fi
if [ -L "demo" ]; then
    echo "-L: true"
fi
```

I found that both "-h" and "-L" can be used to determine whether the specified file is a link. What is the difference between them?

Comment: It's not "in bash". `[` is a *command* that requires its last argument to be `]`, so it *looks* like some special syntax; but it's still a command like `ls` or `cat`. `[ … ]` is equivalent to `test …` where `test` is a command that doesn't look like some special syntax. `[` and `test` are builtins in Bash, but they behave like commands nevertheless. You can use `[` as a standalone executable (it may be `/usr/bin/[`). My point is `-h` and `-L` in question are not directly related to Bash. They belong to the specification of `[` or `test`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, though since it is builtin, anyone using `[` in Bash would get any Bash-specific differences if there were any...

Comment: @ilkkachu `echo` is also a builtin in Bash, but I would expect "what is `-e` in Bash?" to refer to `bash -e`, not to `echo -e`. And there is `[ -e`; and `echo -n` and `[ -n`. By your reasoning, "what is the difference between `-e` and `-n` in bash?" may refer to the `echo` builtin or to the `[` builtin, or to *any* builtin. I reject this ambiguity. The title was wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What is the difference between "-h" and "-L" in bash?

They both exist for legacy reasons, to be compatible between different versions of Unix.

If the system you are running on is not compliant with the latest standards, it may be missing one or the other.

Both forms are present in the [Single Unix Specification version 3/POSIX 2004](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1997680/3536342), with no caveats.

Some versions of Solaris [`test`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) only support `-h`, and (back in 2003) [some software has switched to `-h`](http://marc.info/?l=openssh-unix-dev&m=105612251605017) for compatibility reasons.

So it's probably best to use `-h`

Source: [Difference between test -h and test -L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1997680/3536342), answer by [Brian Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69755/brian-campbell)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at an AlmaLinux 8.7 installation:

1. `man test` indicates the two options are the same:

   ```
       -h FILE
              FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -L)
   <snip>
       -L FILE
              FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -h)
   ```
2. `man bash` just reports the same help text for both options, without mentioning they are the same:

   ```
       -h file
              True if file exists and is a symbolic link.
    <snip>
       -L file
              True if file exists and is a symbolic link.
   ```

From the above man text, it isn't clear which one will have best compatibility with other distributions.

As @DavidPostill has already noted, research is required to identity which option has *best* compatibility.